# notification after an EditText has been modified?

Tags: android

`setOnKeyListener` and `setFilters` notify me before the key/characere is added to the `EditText`.

I would like to be notified after the character has been added to the `EditText`.

One approach I can think of is to override the EditText's `onDraw` but I would like to know if there is a better approache.

TIA

Comment: 4 identical answers... Take your pick.

Comment: wow, looks like it was obvious :o)  Since all answers are the same I will pick the first that came in. Thanks all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `TextWatcher` interface to the `EditText`. 
`TextWatcher` has `afterTextChanged()` method.

Answer (score 4):

Use `addTextChangedListener(TextWatcher watcher)`

Adds a `TextWatcher` to the list of those whose methods are called whenever this TextView's text changes.

[Android TextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener%28android.text.TextWatcher)

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at `TextWatcher`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html

Answer (score 2):

use textwatcher:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html

Answer (score 2):

Use `TextWatcher` as all friend suggest you and override below method

```
  public abstract void afterTextChanged (Editable s){
//Create Notification here by using notification manager
}
```